# How do you create an account using PolkadotJS?

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

The hosted PolkadotJS app allows connected Substrate nodes to use 'Add account' to create a new account on the blockchain.

Using the PolkadotJS NPM package, how can I implement the 'Add account' feature?

[image]

Comment: For context, I am successfully fetching node information, including deployed contracts, by using the ApiPromise created from a WsProvider.

Answer (score 0):

For how-to on accounts in general (including other options):
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-account-generation

For the JS integrations in your app,you can use the apps UI [source](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/page-accounts) as an example.

Internally it uses the keyring package: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/

Comment: I am using keyring package outside of the Polkadot UI. How do I configure the provider that the keyring will add accounts to? (say Kusama, vs. my custom chain)